# Python, Selenium how to ignore shader_cache error?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I keep getting errors like this when running my script (it uses chromedriver):

```
[15796:2516:0519/121100.926:ERROR:platform_sensor_reader_win.cc(242)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
```

Is there an easy way just to ignore these errors because as far as I can tell they're not causing anything but it spams the log up a bit?

Answer (score 0):

It actually isnt an issue with chromedriver but rather with chrome v63 or higher. Chrome v63 has bugs in its ShaderCache which is causing this. The easiest fix is downgrading to chrome v60-61 and using chromedriver v2.33 Worked for me. this is the 'Google Chrome Older Versions' :https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php
,and this is the chrom driver Mirror:http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver/

Hope that resolves your problem

Comment: rolling back to v2.33 completely breaks my script and I still get shader cache errors

Comment: then don't change the chromedriver just downgrade chrome to v60-61

Comment: downgrading doesn't change anything